# Widgets using <h2> for title, rather it be an <h3>

Tags: php, html, css

http://www.christywhiteheadphotography.com/CWPTEST/ (wordpress site)

Part of my theme uses the widgets shown under the slider. Ex. Rainy Day Promotion, Raves, etc.

I want the titles to all display as `<h3>'s` instead of `<h2>'s`.

Appreciate any guidance on how to do this.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: Edit the `post.php` theme file and change the tags from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this (provided you know the name of the sidebar being used for that widget area). This code gets added to `functions.php`:

```
if( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array('name'=>'your_sidebar_name',
        'before_title' => '<h3>', 
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
}
```

However you're probably better off just restyling the `h2's` inside that widget area instead. You could forget the above code and add something like this in your `style.css`:

```
.grid_4 h2 { font-size: 30px }
```

Comment: I just want the font size smaller. That is all :)

Comment: I updated my answer with a css based answer